# Locale Global section in CP bringing back page can not be found

Tags: control-panel, localization, globals

I've been asked about doing a Russian version of a website. I've set up a new locale in the Locale settings, as well as an `ru/` folder with `index.php` and `.htaccess`. Adding a news story in Russian works fine, though changing a *Global* section to Russian brings up a "**Page Cannot be Found**".

The address for this is http://example.com/admin/globals/ru/globals

Does this look right?

**general.php**:

```
return array(
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'en' => 'http://example.com/',
        'en_gb' => 'http://example.com/',
        'ru' => 'http://dropinn.net/ru',
    ),
);
```

**/site/ru** Folder:

```
// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = '../craft';

// Tell Craft to serve the Russian content
define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'ru');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your settings look fine.

Most likely what happened is that when you added the new Russian locale under Settings->Locales, the "Resave All Elements" task that needs to run either didn't get a chance to complete or just ran into an error and failed.

If you don't have any Russian content yet, try deleting the locale and re-adding it - making sure that the task in the upper right hand corner completes.  If you already have Russian content, temporarily add any new locale, let the task complete, then delete the temporary locale.  That will also fix it for the Russian locale.

Comment: Thanks Brad
That could be the problem. "Resaving localizable elements" and "Resaving entries" are stalling. I'm guessing that's a PHP timeout issue. Is there a time limit you use / recommend?

Comment: Depends on the box really. Here are some debugging tips for stalled tasks: http://buildwithcraft.com/help/stuck-tasks